# The miniedit is unavailable to export topology

Tags: python, mininet, sdn, ryu, pox

I am using miniedit to create topologies, the mininet version is 2.3.1b4, installed from git clone. Once I finish and want to export it, the  terminal shows up error messages[image: here is the error message. shown as TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects]:

can anyone please assist me how to solve this issue? many thanks